# from Bootstrap to laravel form for single select box with title

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

```
<select class="selectpicker" title="Please Select...">
<option data-hidden="true"></option>
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
<option>Onions</option>
```

This is the bootstrap single select box, from which how can I get the laravel formatted query for the above code.How should I add  the data-hidden without value attribute

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it?
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3948/
Try this. Differents variants:

```
<select class="selectpicker" title="Please Select...">
<option hidden></option>   <!-- hidden="true" or class="hide" or hidden -->
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
<option>Onions</option>
```